# How long does it take to refuel a Cessna Citation X+?

Tags: ground-operations, refueling, cessna-citation

Does anyone have any sources that can tell the the number of fueling nozzles and the fueling rate for a Cessna Citation X+ or a Cessna Citation X?

Answer (score 2):

Basically fuelling time depends on how fast the hydrant or fuel truck can deliver fuel.

This comes from [SmartCockpit](http://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/Cessna_Citation_X-Fuel.pdf):

> The  Citation  X  fuel  system  is  comprised  of  the  storage,
> distribution,  refueling/defueling,and  indicating  systems.    The
> storage  system  is  made  up  of  a  set  of  integral  tanks  in
> each wing,  and  a  center  wing  tank  which  includes  a  forward
> fairing  fuel  tank.    Each  wing  tank  has  a hopper  tank  which
> is  integral  to  it.    The  two  wing  tanks  incorporate  check
> valves  and  baffles allowing  each  wing  tank  complex  to  function
> as  a  single  tank.    Other  integral  components  of the  storage
> system  are  the  gravity  fuel  fillers,  drain  valves,  flapper
> check  valves,  vent  system                      components,
> positive/negative   pressure   relief   valves   and   all   of   the
> associated   system plumbing.    Transfer  capability  is
> incorporated  enabling  all  usable  fuel  to  be  available  to
> either engine.Each  wing  tank  holds  a  total  of  521  gallons
> (3518  Lbs.)  of  fuel,  which  includes  the  hopper tank.    The
> center  wing  tank  holds  888  gallons  (5594  Lbs.),  207  (1397
> Lbs.)  of  which  are contained  in  the  forward  fairing  tank.
> Total  fuel  capacity  of  the  airplane  fuel  system  is
> 1927 gallons; at 6.75 pounds per gallon the available fuel weight is
> 13,031 pounds.
>
> SINGLE-POINT REFUELING DEFUELING SYSTEM
>
> The  single-point  refueling  system  is  provided  to  enable  the
> airplane  to  be  refueled  or    de-fueled  more  safely  and
> conveniently  by  connecting  to  one  port,  which  is  not  open  to
> the atmosphere.      Advantages   of   a   single-point   refueling
> and   defueling   include   minimized refuel/defuel   time,   reduced
> possibilities   of   fuel   contamination,   reduced   static
> electricity hazard, less airplane skin damage, and there is no
> personnel contact with the fuel.The  refueling/defueling  system  is
> independent  of  the  airplane  system.    It  is  designed  for
> refueling  with  a  truck  or  refueling  hydrant  (pit)  having
> single  point  provisions.    The  major components  of  the  system
> include  the  refueling/defueling  adapter  (receptacle),  the
> precheck control  panel,  refuel  shutoff  valves,  the  pilot
> (precheck)  valves,  defuel  valves,  a  sequencing valve,   manual
> defuel   select   shutoff   valves,   internal   drain   valves   and
> associated   system plumbing.Single-point  refueling  is  accomplished
> by  connecting  the  refueling  truck  or  refueling  pit equipment
> to  the  airplane  at  the  single-point  refuel/defuel  adapter  on
> the  right  side  of  the fuselage just forward of the wing leading
> edge.

Comment: Just as a *really* general idea, however, single point fueling trucks fairly routinely have flow rates in the vicinity of 200-250 US gallons per minute.

Comment: So from empty to full would take about 10 minutes at the lower rate of 200 gpm